# I need help converting data all in one row to multiple rows

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data excel sheet like this;

[image: [EXCEL](http://i.imgur.com/mnvXLSQ.jpg)]

I would like the `b` column to be converted into 3 new columns, so there are two lines like `URL1, Name, address, email` and `URL3, Name, address, email`.

Answer (score 2):

With data in columns **A** and **B**, in **C1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($A$1,3*(ROWS($1:1)-1),0)
```

and copy down and in **D1** enter:

```
=OFFSET($B$1,COLUMNS($A:A)-1+(ROW()-1)*3,0)
```

and copy BOTH across and down:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Open Visual Basic (Press **Alt+F11**) 
Insert a Module and paste following code into that Module

```
Sub Macro()
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, LastRow As Integer
LastRow = Sheets(1).Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
Sheets(2).Cells(1, 1).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1).Value
Sheets(2).Cells(1, 2).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 2).Value
k = 1
j = 2
For i = 1 To LastRow
    If Sheets(1).Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets(1).Range("A" & (i + 1)).Value Then
        j = j + 1
        Sheets(2).Cells(k, j).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
    Else
        k = k + 1
        Sheets(2).Cells(k, 1).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 1).Value
        Sheets(2).Cells(k, 2).Value = Sheets(1).Cells(i + 1, 2).Value
        j = 2
        End If
Next i
End Sub
```

This code checks for the similarity between the cells in the first column, if the cell content matches then value in the cell next to it will be copied to another sheet. If the cell content in first column doesn't match then it will be considered as next data point.

Input in first sheet 
[image]

Output in second sheet 
[image]